# Breaking Google Analytics sessions on mobile

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an Android app and I am using Google Tag Manager to create the tags.

I have a specif screen that should reset the session everytime the user opens it, but I don't know how to do it.
Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Session Control](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#sc) parameter. Or you could use the [Manual Session Control](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/sessions#manual):

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Set screen name.
t.setScreenName(screenName);

// Start a new session with the hit.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
    .setNewSession()
    .build());
```

Good luck

Comment: Starting manual new sessions can cause double counts in GAv4. GA sometimes determines and starts sessions by it self. using dryrun look for sc=start you'll see duplicates.